# Javascript: Link with id

Tags: php, javascript, html

This isn't really a problem so much as a general question. I don't have much experience with javascript, and I wrote this a few months ago and now I can't remember why it works. I have the following code in a php file:

```
    echo'<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="button_js.js"></SCRIPT>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Nickname" name="nickname" id="nickname" />
     <br />

        <a href="example.com" id="submit_request">Submit Request</a> |
        <a href="example.com" id="continue_searching">Continue Searching</a>';
```

Inside button_js.js, there is a submit_request function and a continue_searching function. When the user clicks the corresponding link, the appropriate function executes just like I want it to; everything works perfectly.

The problem is that I can't remember for the life of me why this works. How does it know to execute the correct function based on the user clicking on the link? I don't have an onClick in there anywhere. Is it just because the names of the functions match the id's of the links?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: We need to see the snippet from the javascript to answer your question. We're not magicians.

Comment: search for $('#submit_request').click(submit_request); or something like that

Comment: @phpisuber01 Speak for yourself. But yes, we need to see the contents of button_js.js. There's probably some click listeners in there somewhere that are attaching themselves to the links.

Comment: Somewhere you must be binding the event handler to the element. The code you posted is useless for the question though.

Comment: What might be faster is searching for "continue_searching" in the script or on the page. One will be the function, and the other what calls the function. Where the function is called from is probably the trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the code in your script, I can only guess... But it's very likely you are adding an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) (sometimes incorrectly called an "event handler", which is different but related to your question).

In short, JavaScript has the ability to "grab" elements in your page and "listen" for events that might happen to them (such as click).  Once that event happens, you trigger a function (or "handle" that event with an... "event handler").

If you're using jQuery, the concept is the same, however you may find that you're using [jQuery's own event handling functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-handler-attachment/).

Comment: Yep, I just missed where I added the listener. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Providing the relevent JavaScript code would help others help you.

With that said, I will give you a general answer.

There is an event listener that fires when the user clicks. When the event fires, it gets value of the id attribute. Then, if the id attribute has a function name that corresponds to its value, the event then calls that function.

E.g., in JQuery (completely untested):

```
$("a").click(function(ev) {
  var f = this[ev.target.id];

  if (typeof f === 'function')
     f(); // calls the function whose name corresponds to the id attribute
});
```